# fnc 12 key not working in vscode for the language c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I have intellisense installed in vscode but by pressing f12 it is working for methods defined by me but not working for class like console and not working for methods like Length which is predefined I want to know why?

I did install the c# dev kit after trying f12 but not working
I am expecting the working of f12 key for inbuilt methods and classes of c#

Comment: Welcome! Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. What do you see when you [troubleshoot your keybindings](//github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues)? Please paste the relevant parts of what you see into a code block in your question post. Include also the top section of the file opened by running `Developer: Inspect Key Mappings` in the command palette and all following text that is related to the keys of interest.